# How to write form tag in codeignter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have use codeignter, I need to write form tag using codeignter how to do this
I don't need normal html form tag.

```
<Form>
```

I don't need like this

Comment: you can use form helper :- https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of form helper in codeigniter.

```
<?php
    echo form_open('create_user.php', ['id' => 'frmUsers']); #formTagOpen
        
    echo form_label('User Id', 'user_id'); #formLabel
    echo form_input(['name' => 'user_id']); #formInput
        
    echo form_label('Password', 'password'); #formLabel
    echo form_input(['type' => 'password', 'name' => 'password']); #formInputPassword
        
    echo form_submit('btnSubmit', 'Create User'); #formSubmitButton
        
    echo form_close(); #formClosingTag
?>
```

To learn more you can refer [this](https://www.guru99.com/codeigniter-form-validation.html#2)